# Pagination to show max value and limit the rest

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, pagination

Right now my pagination would show up something like this

[1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [6] [7] [8] [9]

How would i make it show up like this

[1] [2] [3] [4] [5]... [9]

```
<?php
$per_page = 10;
$pages_query = mysql_query ("SELECT COUNT(`message_id`) FROM `messages`") or die(mysql_error());
$pages = ceil(mysql_result ($pages_query, 0) / $per_page);
$page = (isset ($_GET['page'])) ? (int) $_GET['page'] : 1; 
$start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;
?>
```

Relevant if statement that echo out pagination

```
<?php
    if ($pages >=1 && $page <= $pages) {
        for ($x=1; $x<=$pages;$x++) {
            echo "<a href=\"?page=" .$x."\">".$x."</a>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: [offtopic] When you have huge data to manage, rather then putting them in multiple pages, put them in a single page but show only a small number of results initially, say, 10. As the user scrolls down, load the other things using XMLHttpRequest asynchronously. Just like google does with Image search or like DuckDuckGo.[/offtopic].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this :

```
    <?php
        $link = "";
 // $page = $_GET['page'];
 // $pages=20; // Hardcoded for testing purpose
  $limit=5  ;
    if ($pages >=1 && $page <= $pages)
    {
        $counter = 1;
        $link = "";
        if ($page > ($limit/2))
           { $link .= "<a href=\"?page=1\">1 </a> ... ";}
        for ($x=$page; $x<=$pages;$x++)
        {

            if($counter < $limit)
                $link .= "<a href=\"?page=" .$x."\">".$x." </a>";

            $counter++;
        }
        if ($page < $pages - ($limit/2))
         { $link .= "... " . "<a href=\"?page=" .$pages."\">".$pages." </a>"; }
    }

    echo $link;
?>
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
//At page=1
1 2 3 4 ... 20 

//At page=12
1 ... 12 13 14 15 ... 20 

//At page=18
1 ... 18 19 20
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
    if ($pages >=1 && $page <= $pages) {
        $counter = 1;
        $link = "";
        for ($x=1; $x<=$pages;$x++) {
            if($counter < 5)
                $link .= "<a href=\"?page=" .$x."\">".$x."</a>";

            $counter++;
        }
        $link .= "...";
        $link .=  "<a href=\"?page=" .$pages."\">".$pages."</a>";
    }
    echo $link;
?>
```

Comment: this line has a syntax error, I'll try to fix it, but do you know what's causing it?        $link .= "..." . <a href=\"?page=" .$pages."\">".$pages."</a>;

Comment: Seems wrong ... It will always show  1234..20 , irrespective of which page you will be in

Comment: @Makesh - yes you are right we would need to check that condition also. but here is just asked about showing that long item list in that '...' format

Comment: okay i fixed it... this just shows the top result and not the rest. ie it just echos "...9"

Comment: @thedullmistro: Please try now. I made a small mistake. Sorry.

Comment: Gives an error "Syntax error unexpected '<' "
coming from this line
        $link .=  <a href=\"?page=" .$pages."\">".$pages."</a>;