# Count rows with variable and pagination?

Tags: php, mysql

I recently had a script that worked where I could count the rows in a table with a variable like so:

```
$i = 1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query5)) {
  echo "$i";
  echo "<br />";
  $i++;
}
```

However, I recently implemented this pagination script here http://papermashup.com/easy-php-pagination/ which ruins it. As I go to the second page, it counts the rows all over again and starts identifying each row as #1. However, I would like it to continue to name the same row # from the previous page. Is this possible?

Comment: you increment `$i` after loop which will result in list of zeros

Comment: This may help you : Check out the question and answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15241847/pagination-to-show-max-value-and-limit-the-rest/15242313#15242313

Comment: why not use mysqli_num_rows() for it

Comment: $InsaneBits my bad, I had it right on my script but I copied it over wrong on StackOverflow. It's corrected now. The problem is it's not carrying over the $i variable to the next page. I'm not entirely sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have page number somewhere, so start counting from page number * items per page

```
$i = $page_number * $page_size + 1;// assuming page_number starts from 0
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query5))
{
    echo "$i";
    echo "<br />";
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: That's almost it but not quite. If I use $i = $page * $limit; and I have a limit of 2 and i am on page 2, it will display the first row as 4 when it would actually be 3.... I can't get the proper equation.

Comment: NVM, I ended up finding a solution that just involved little editing to your equation. Thank you very much :)